# display menu as table layout

Tags: menus, css, navigation, table

I want the menu of this [site](http://www.jokerleb.com/) to look like the menu of this [site](http://olx.com/).

It's clear that they use display table and table cell but not sure how to implement it, been playing with css for a while, couldn't nail it. Didn't found a plugin that does the job but css should do. Do I have to create a custom menu layout? I think not.

I'm using a wordpress menu with this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-icons/), and the header.php

```
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'menu-header', 'fallback_cb' => false, 'container' => false ) ); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( CP_ADD_NEW_URL ); ?>" class="obtn btn_orange"><?php _e( 'Post an Ad', APP_TD ); ?></a>

    <div class="clr"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing my answer. See the screenshot, if it's close enough to what you're looking for, try adding the following to your stylesheet.

[image: adjusted your styles via firefox element inspector]

```
.header_menu_res ul li {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    width: 25%;
}

.menu-item i._mi, .menu-item img._mi {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.menu-item span {
    margin-top: 8px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Comment: please read my edit

Comment: perfect thank you! next time you edit your question or answer please leave a comment notifying the person you want to inform for example @Lynob so that the website sends me a notification